# Bluetooth LE Privacy

Tags: apple-id, bluetooth

Is there a way to turn off or bypass Bluetooth Privacy on iPhone 5/6/7? I want to be able to sniff my phone's actual BT MAC address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's no way to turn it off.